# Deferred member construction

Tags: c++, constructor

I have the following struct:

```
struct Logger::LoggerImpl {
    std::wofstream loggerStream;
}
```

When I create a LoggerImpl, obviously a std::wofstream will be created implicitly (via the compiler's default constructor).

My question is, is there a way to prevent (or defer) the construction of the wofstream, without using a pointer? Because I will create it later on with a given filename.

I know that in this case it makes little difference, but I'm asking on a theoretical basis.

Comment: "without using a pointer" - any reason for that? A pointer seems like an obvious solution. Just having it there will obviously allocate it during initialization, and if you have a reference that obviously can't be null at any stage too.

Comment: If it's not a pointer, it will be constructed at the same time the parent is constructed; not much you can do about that. The only other choice is called two-part construction but that would be for the `wofstream` class, not your `Logger` class.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without a pointer? Is there a reason?

Comment: [Boost Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html).

Comment: @Benjamin Well, I prefer not to use pointers if I can at the moment - I'm still a C++ beginner. Also I'm wary (in future cases) of heap fragmentation etc. Plus, I guess, I'm just trying to learn.

Comment: Avoiding fragmentation is usually a case of premature optimization. If you find that your process could really benefit from avoiding memory fragmentation you could look at [memory pools](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/boost_pool/pool/introduction.html).

Comment: @jrok: unrestricted unions, too. It probably makes sense to use them as an implementation for something like an `optional<T>`, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, if you stretch the definition of "without using a pointer" to mean "without having to use `std::wofstream *` directly":

```
struct Logger::LoggerImpl {
    std::shared_ptr<std::wofstream> loggerStream;


    void init () {
        loggerStream = std::make_shared<std::wofstream> ();
    }
};
```

I say stretched because you're not dealing with `std::wofstream *` directly. That's the best I can come up with.

Comment: _[Okay, so you already admitted that. Still, I felt it needed saying, curtly, in a single comment. :P The long and short is that you didn't answer the question, BUT I suspect this is the correct approach for the OP, since at least he still has RAII on his side. +1]_

Comment: Well, if you think about it, you pretty much can't use the STL without using pointers, because they're all implemented using pointers internally. Even if you declare a `std::wofstream` on the stack, you're still using pointer, right? Same thing here, I think. The `std::shared_ptr` uses the pointer directly, and you use it indirectly.

Comment: @anthony-arnold Interesting point. It seems there's no real way of doing what I want (other than just declaring the space as a char* and manually serializing... But I'm not gonna go there :)). So I will accept this answer.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: At the lowest level of abstraction, sure, your entire program is basically composed of pointers and jump points. But there's not much point rationalising about that. The OP is talking about code that he writes.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, so in my example, there are no pointers.

Comment: @anthony-arnold: I still say `shared_ptr` is a pointer even in code-land. You didn't write `*`, but you are explicitly using pointer semantics in code that you write. But, yes, I _did_ upvote you after all.

Answer (score 5):

Why not create the `std::wofstream` with the default constructor and later just `open()` the file? Binding the life-time of a contained object seems the correct approach.

In C++11 you can also put objects with constructors into a `union`. The upshot is, of course, that you will need to take over the life-time management of the `union` member. This way you can, however, defer the construction of a particular member until later. Note the at the use of `new` in the code below is actually just *placement new*, constructing an object into a suitable location. Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <new>

class foo
{
    bool constructed;
    union helper {
        helper() {}
        ~helper() {}
        std::ifstream stream;
    } member;
public:
    foo(): constructed() {}
    ~foo() {
        if (constructed) {
            using std::ifstream;
            this->member.stream.~ifstream();
        }
    }
    void open(std::string const& name) {
        new (&this->member.stream) std::ifstream(name);
        constructed = true;
    }
    std::streambuf* rdbuf() {
        return this->member.stream.rdbuf();
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo f;
    f.open("foo.cpp");
    std::cout << f.rdbuf();
}
```

Comment: This is the only post that actually answers how to defer member construction without using a pointer (and by that, heap allocated memory).

Answer (score 1):

It makes a lot of sense to defer construction of members in a variety of situation. Here are a couple ways to do that; the difference between implementations is due to different purpose of deferral.

Initialization on first use; reason: not wasting resources until needed.

```
class Logger::LoggerImpl 
{
private:
    std::wofstream * loggerStream; // Don't expose to other classes

    std::wofstream * GetLoggerStreamImpl()
    {
        if( loggerStream == NULL )
        {
            loggerStream = new std::wofstream;
        }

        return loggerStream;
    }

public:
    LoggerImpl() : loggerStream(NULL) 
    {
    }

    std::wofstream * GetLoggerStream()
    {
        return GetLoggerStreamImpl();
    }

    void DoSomethingWithLoggerStream()
    {
        GetLoggerStreamImpl();
        // Do whatever you need with loggerStream
    }
};
```

Initialization by a dedicated method; reason: the parameter for initialization was not known before.

```
class Logger::LoggerImpl 
{
private:
    std::wofstream * loggerStream; // Don't expose to other classes

    std::wofstream * OpenLoggerStreamImpl( string filename )
    {
        if( loggerStream == NULL )
        {
            loggerStream = new std::wofstream( filename );
        }
        return loggerStream;
    }

public:
    LoggerImpl() : loggerStream(NULL) 
    {
    }

    std::wofstream * OpenLoggerStream( string filename )
    {
        return OpenLoggerStreamImpl( filename );
    }

    void DoSomethingWithLoggerStream()
    {
        if( loggerStream == NULL )
        {
            throw Exception( "Aye, Caramba! Logging stream wasn't open yet!" );
        }

        // Do whatever you need with loggerStream
    }
};
```

Comment: Considering the OP mentions their beginner C++ status, let me just point out you must delete the `loggerStream`, probably in the destructor of `LoggerImpl`. Alternatively, see my answer for how to have your pointer automatically cleaned up when it goes out of scope.